# error time out al realizar peticion https a servidor nginx

Tags: nginx, https

estoy intentando realizar peticiones https a un servidor nginx que redirecciona a al servidor de node donde se ejecuta las peticiones pero me genera error time out pero al realizar la peticion con http si me realiza las peticiones bien. necesito hacer las peticiones con https ya que mi frontend tiene certificado ssl. aqui les colocare como tengo configurado nginx. aqui les presento la configuración que tengo en conf.d/default.conf. cabe destacar que tengo tambien habilitado ufw con la regla de permitir solicitudes por el puerto 443 y nginx https.

```
server{
listen 443 http2 ssl;
listen [::]:443 http2 ssl;
root /usr/share/nginx/html;
server_name loscincosabores.store;
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/loscincosabores.store/fullchain.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/loscincosabores.store/privkey.pem;    
ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;
include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;

location /{
    proxy_set_header        Host $host;
            proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;

    }
}
```

asi esta el nginx.conf

```
events {
worker_connections 768;
# multi_accept on;



http{

##
# Basic Settings
##

sendfile on;
tcp_nopush on;
types_hash_max_size 2048;
# server_tokens off;

# server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
# server_name_in_redirect off;

include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
default_type application/octet-stream;

##
# SSL Settings
##

ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

##
# Logging Settings
##

access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

##
# Virtual Host Configs
##

include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

he buscado de todo en internet y esta es la ultima configuracion que he establecido.